# Different persistence.xml properies for test run / JPA Fixtures

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I develop some Java EE/Spring web-app. I use JPA 2.0 - Hibernate. For integration tests I need to use different database. Those tests require Jetty to run application, but I managed to override web.xml for such run, there I can modify my Spring context files, it's ok.
But I need each time a clean database (and load some data into it).
As my database name and address are configured in sprig context I just switched them as I described above - but how can I change some of my persistence.xml properies for this tests only to have database drop and recreated?
I tried to make another persistence.xml in /src/test/resources/META-INF (and checked that test-classes are first in classpath) but it is not loaded and only the 'master' version is used (from /src/main/resources/META-INF). Any help?

Answer (score 0):

With spring you usually define your data source as a spring bean. The database url and credentials are usually included form an external file, for example application.properties.

If you put a new applicaiton.properties in `src/test/resources` it will work. [See also here](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=118).

Comment: yes I know, but problem is with persistence.xml not with Spring contex - I would like to change <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>

Comment: aha.. well, I have externalized properties as well to be configured to spring, but that requires an extension of one of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can define **org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager** :

```
<bean id="pum" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
       <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
         <list>
           <value>/path/to/my/test-persistence.xml</value>
         </list>
       </property>
       <property name="dataSources">
         <map>
           <entry key="dataSource" value-ref="dataSource"/>
         </map>
       </property>
       <!-- if no datasource is specified, use this one -->
       <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Then, link it to your entityManagerFactory :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    ...
    ...
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum"/>
</bean>
```

I used this to make my own persistence.xml linked to a HSQL in-memory db, preloaded with DBUnit (using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop).

It Works perfectly.